# Floating Menu Variable Width

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to have a floating navigation bar to the left of the content, that is fixed width but has a container around it that extends to the edge of the viewport while keeping the content centered on the page.

And here's what I got going so far and an image of what I mean. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23132/index.html

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution from [Bordingo](http://designinformer.com/forums/topic/floating-menu-variable-width?replies=3#post-1204).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {    height: 100%;    min-width: 960px;}

.container { width: 960px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: #ddd; }

.nav-fix { position: absolute; left: 0; width: 50%; min-width: 480px;  height: 100%;}

.nav { position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 280px; width: 9999px; height: 200px; background: #333; }

.nav-box { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; width: 180px; height: 180px; background: #eee; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-fix">
<div class="nav">
<div class="nav-box"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No luck with the dynamic height of the nav area though ?

Comment: They dynamic height seems to work, the height is just in the example to hold the shape without adding content for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jQuery, you can pretty easily calculate the offset of the main body and adjust the width/padding/margin of the sidebar accordingly.

Simple example

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1588084/floatmenu.htm

Comment: Two problems. It doesn't center the content area and the menu area into a centered position. The other is that the content area slips under the menu at smaller sizes. 

I tried it out here. 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23132/New%20Folder/index2.html

Comment: This is the same technique but I've changed it to be closer to your mockup, I think.  Keeps the menu and content centered, no slide-under.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1588084/floatmenu_2.htm

Comment: Still doesn't work quite right. The menu and the sidebar are to be in a fixed position and when I try to do that with your version it falls apart. The menu and the fluid part are also going to have content in it that changes so they need to be the same height dynamicly.